# Sending data through Unwind Segues

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, segue, unwind-segue

I have a custom unwind segue issue. Let me explain my controller setup:

I have a main screen which is a navigation controller with a cell view inside. Within this view, there is a button to add data, and in that view is 4 buttons for additional "types" of data to add. Once a user selects one of those four options, they are presented with a view controller specific to their choice that lets them enter data with a done button. The three screens respectively I will from now on refer to them as Main View, Options View, then Data View(all 4 options follow this convention).

After some tutorials I made a custom unwind segue in Main View's controller class, as follows:

```
@IBAction func unwindToTables(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    //function proto for adding data here
    //populateTableWithData(data :ItemData)
}
```

In the storyboard editor, anytime I `control` + `click` from any View Controller to it's exit, it lists my unwind segue properly and this works fine.

I would now like to send data through the unwind. In Data View, I have a Done button that constructs and initializes a class of data, called ItemData to which I would like to pass through the segue.

Most of the questions I found on SO or other sites with this deals with normal segues, and when I try to implement them anyways the application causes a runtime error / does not compile.

Has anyone come into the issue before, and have a solution for said issue? Any help or points in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Edit:

I edited my unwind function as follows:

```
@IBAction func unwindToTables(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    let dataC = segue.sourceViewController as? DataVC
    let data : ItemData = dataC!.SubmittedData! //unwrapping error

    print(data.Name)


    //save data

}
```

and on top of every New{1-4}ViewController I have the following:

```
import UIKit

class New1ViewController: DataVC,
```

and I made a new superclass DataVC:

```
import Foundation

class DataVC: UITableViewController {
    var SubmittedData: ItemData?
}
```

but now I am getting an unwrapping issue... must I initialize SubmittedData prior?

Edit 2:

Thought I might add the Done button press I am doing...

```
@IBAction func DonePressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    let n = ...
    ...
    let d = ...

    super.SubmittedData = ItemData(FieldType: "1", CName: n!, CPhone: p!, CAddress: a!, ShouldBe: s!, Repeats: r!, Starts: b, RemindMe: m!, AdditionalNotes: d!)

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UIStoryboardSegue` that is passed to your `unwindToTables:` function has a property `sourceViewControllee` this will be the instance of your `Data` view controller.

You need all of your view controllers to inherit from a common superclass, so that you can add the property you need:

```
class DataVC: UITableViewController {
    var submittedData: ItemData?
}
```

Then you would have something like:

```
class New1ViewController: DataVC,... {
...
}
```

Then in your unwind method you can retrieve the `submittedData` property

```
@IBAction func unwindToTables(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let dataVC = segue.sourceViewController as? DataVC {
      if let info = dataVC.submittedData {
         ...
      }
    }
 }
```

Comment: So in your assumption I actually have separate classes for each view controller. I went ahead in the Data View class and did this `var dataValues : ItemData` outside of any methods (global var pretty much) to which I populate in my Done button press. Now when I go to the Main View's controller class and put what you put (modified of course) I cannot access that var because it is internal, and typing public causes an error with initializers (???).

Comment: If you add a property you either need to initialise it or declare it as an optional. I would suggest the optional approach, which would mean unwrapping it hen you access it

Comment: I just realized I might be running into the issue that I am checking for four different viewcontrollers... see my edit to see if you can confirm this...

Comment: Yes, that is why I said you need all of your view controllers to inherit from a common superclass.  This superclass would add your `itemData`.  Let me update my answer to show what I mean

Comment: Sweet! I got the property to work now (updated my post accordingly) however I am getting a runtime error with unwrapping the variable...

Comment: You should be able to say `self.submittedData`, not `super.`.  How are you triggering your unwind segue?  You will need to call `performSegueWithIdentifier` after you have set `submittedData`.  If you trigger it straight from the `done` button in Interface Builder the property won't be set.  My code shouldn't give an exception since I conditionally unwrap.  Where are you getting the exception?

Comment: I was segue-ing from storyboard, but just changed that. So anyways, wow. Thank you so much! I learned a lot with your help! Wish I could upvote you more than just once. Thanks for the patience with my ignorance and thanks for the valuable knowledge!